# How to fade in closest image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried writing a small script to Fadein the closest image using jQuery but for some reasons this code is not working. Can anyone help me with the syntax? Thanks

```
$( ".delimg" ).click(function() {
  $(this).closest( "img" ).fadeTo( "slow" , 0.5, function() {
      $("input[type='button']").toggle(
         function(){
             $(this).val("Undelete");
       }, 
          function(){
             $(this).val("Delete");
       }
);
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="swiper-slide">
    <img src="http://20percents.com/backend/uploads/C0d49a7de7b635477125ffffa8df7b931.jpg" class="swipe-image">
    <center><input type="button" class="delimg" value="Delete"></center>
</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">
    <img src="http://20percents.com/backend/uploads/C0d49a7de7b635477125ffffa8df7b932.jpg" class="swipe-image">
    <center><input type="button" class="delimg" value="Delete"></center>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e27r8/597/

Comment: `closest` is for looking for the closest parent and since your image tag is not a parent of `.delimg` that's why it will no work

Comment: @Huangism - I didn't new difference between `find` and `closest` till now and I thought `closest` does the job of `find`. Just now understood that `closest` can't recognise if there is any more tags in between.

Comment: for more info http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `img` element is not a direct parent of the button which is clicked. You need to use closest to get the containing div, then search for the image within that. Try this:

```
$(".delimg").click(function () {
    $(this).closest(".swiper-slide").find('img').fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e27r8/600/)

Also, note that `toggle` can no longer be used in the manner you are. It will only show/hide elements now, not run specific functions on successive clicks.

To change the text of the button as required, you can pass a function to `val()` like this:

```
$(".delimg").click(function () {
    var $button = $(this);
    $button.closest(".swiper-slide").find('img').fadeTo("slow", 0.5, function() {
        $button.val(function(i, value) {
            return value == "Delete" ? "Undelete" : "Delete";
        });
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e27r8/602/)

Comment: Fade is working fine but the Undelete/Delete is not working. Its removing the button.

Comment: Thank you, working but how can I setup toggle fadein upon undelete? I tried using `fadetoggle` and `toggle.fade` but both didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an ancestor, so you need to traverse -

```
$(this).closest( ".swiper-slide" ).find("img").fadeTo( "slow" , 0.5, function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

As `img` is not parent of `input` so,you have to do this way:

```
 $(this).closest(".swiper-slide").find("img")
```

You have to get parent div with class `swiper-slide` and then get `img` from inside it.

Answer (score 0):

you should go up one level, and then find

```
$(...).parent().find(...);



$( ".delimg" ).click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find( "img" ).fadeTo( "slow" , 0.5, function() {
      $("input[type='button']").toggle(
         function(){
             $(this).val("Undelete");
       }, 
          function(){
             $(this).val("Delete");
       }
);
  });
});
```

edit

i missed `<center>` tag
use `.parent().parent()`

Comment: This will not work, the parent of .delimg is <center> tag.
If you want to use parent you should use parent().parent()

Comment: @lock 
use like Pawet Andruszkow said, but
$(this).parent().parent().children('img').fadeTo( ... )

Comment: you're right, i missed <center> tag. parent().parent() should help

Comment: But closest() and find() is so much more faster ( almost 50% faster)
http://jsperf.com/jquery-comparison-parent-closes